# Is the spectral distribution equal to boltzmann distribution?

Tags: thermal-radiation, spectroscopy

The [Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution) provides information about the speed of particles of a gas:

[image: Plot]

Speed is actually kinetic energy which is connected to temperature via $ E_{kin} = 0.5 * m * v^2 = 3/2 * kT$. Hence, I wonder wether a [spectral distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_body#:%7E:text=A%20black%20body%20or%20blackbody,can%20emit%20black%2Dbody%20radiation.) can be expressed in terms of a Maxwell-Boltzmann-distribution? Is it even the same? It looks very similar in some cases and in others not.

[image: Plot2]

Comment: Actually both of them can be derived from canonical partition function. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(statistical_mechanics)

Comment: Ok, that's over my head..

Comment: If the two distributions were the same, Planck would not have invented quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

1. The Spectral Distribution tells us about the distribution of Spectral Irradiance with Wavelength.
2. The Boltzmann Distribution gives the probability of particles to be found in a range of different speeds.

But Boltzmann Distribution is NOT same as the Spectral Distribution as both these distributions represent different physical quantities. Spectral Irradiance (in Spectral Distribution) talks about the Intensity of light and the photon flux while the Probability Density (in Boltzmann Distribution) gives the statistical information about the number density of particles moving with various speeds.

Though the graphs appear to be quite similar for both the distributions but they aren't the same things.

To support the above line, a similar argument can be given for the curves of $y = 1/x^2$ and $y = 1/x^4$ , although they look quite similar but they represent totally different functions ! In layman's term, all that glitters is not Gold !!
[image: This figure was plotted by me in Python using Matplotlib module]

NOTE : This is my first ever answer and my first experience on Stack Exchange, I am new here, if I made any mistake, I am open to any comments and improvement. The graph shown here was plotted using Python that's why I can't include any link for the photo of the graph.